# No column has NA but with error "arguments imply differing number of rows:"

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

Tried to use ols_step_both_p to find the best model for Train dataset. But keep getting the error after running the following:

```
house_sales <- read.csv("Sales.csv")

house_sales <- subset(house_sales, select = -c(id, lat, long, zipcode))
house_sales$date <- as.numeric(substr(house_sales$date, 1, 8))
house_sales$price <- as.numeric(gsub('[\\$,]', '', house_sales$price))

library(caret)
set.seed(1023)

DataSplit <- createDataPartition(house_sales$price, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)

TrainData <- house_sales[DataSplit,]
TestData <- house_sales[-DataSplit,]

full_model <- lm(price~., data = TrainData)

library(olsrr)
ols_step_both_p(full_model, pent=0.1, prem=0.05, details=TRUE)
```

Error:

> Error in data.frame(model = rep(seq_len(all_step), lbetas), predictor
> = names(betas),  :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 100, 92

Searched online for reason and it looks like it's because some columns' row numbers are different. Tried to see if there is any column containing NA:

```
apply(TrainData, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

and the result:

> ```
>      date         price      bedrooms     bathrooms   sqft_living 
>         0             0             0             0             0 
>  sqft_lot        floors    waterfront          view     condition 
>         0             0             0             0             0 
>     grade    sqft_above sqft_basement      yr_built  yr_renovated 
>         0             0             0             0             0  
>  sqft_living15    sqft_lot15 
>         0             0
> ```

And checked all columns in Train dataset, they have the same number of rows.

Here is the link of the public data:
[KC_House_Sales](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction)

You can also see this link:
[KC_House_Sales](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wWfeCRneDWuuKhKeYVYGT4GIBpZf832R/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You should add an example of your `TrainData` object, otherwise it will be difficult to help you because the error may be related to your own data

Comment: Thx I have added data. @Basti